# Moving an image file in php from a tmp directory to a permanent one (using Laravel)

Tags: php, http, post, laravel, fopen

I am trying to move an image file previously uploaded into a tmp directory to a permament location. I have used this tutorial as a starting point:

```
maxoffsky.com/code-blog/uploading-files-in-laravel-4/
```

I have amended the code as I am uploading the files earlier and accessing them later through a url provided by the form. The code below shows what I am doing:

```
$form_element = "image_1"; // hidden form element containing the tmp location
$tmp_path = $form_data[$form_element]; // gets the tmp url from hidden element
$file = fopen($tmp_path, 'r'); // opens the file

$destinationPath = 'images/adverts/'.$advert->id; // specifies a new folder
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // retrieves the name of the file
$upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename); // moves the file to its new location
```

The problem I am having is that in the tutorial, they use the code:

```
$file = Input::file('file'); // Laravel syntax for $_POST['file']
```

This retrieves the file from the html form itself. From there the functions `$file->getClientOriginalName()` and `$file->move()` work correctly.

However, in mine, as my form doesnt provide an actual file, just a link to one, I am trying to access the file and perform the same operations, however I get this error:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
```

I dont think that `fopen()` is returning the same type as `$_POST['file']` hence it isnt working.

How can I make my code work?

Many thanks

Comment: What is `$advert` and what is `$form_data`?

Comment: `$file` is empty... I think.

Comment: $Advert is a model I am using. $form_data is an array containing all of the http post information sent to the method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, just add in the Form::open in array the enctype:

`enctype='multipart/form-data'`

and your problems are solved! I have forgotten it and banging my head to the wall after that I started harder to bang it when I saw it.

PS. You have a little misconception. Input::file('file') it's not syntax for $_POST['file'], but for $_FILES['file']